# Python: re.findall() does not work for overlapping substrings

Tags: python, regex

I want to match a string with a list of values. These can be overlapping, so for example `string = "test1 test2"` and `values = ["test1", "test1 test2"]`.

EDIT: Below is my entire code for a simple example

```
import regex    

string = "This is a test string"
values = ["test", "word", "string", "test string"]

pattern = r'\b({})\b'.format('|'.join(map(regex.escape, values)))
matches = set(map(str.lower, regex.findall(pattern, string, regex.IGNORECASE)))

output = ([x.upper() for x in values if x.lower() in matches])

print(output) # ['TEST', 'STRING']
# Expected output:  ['TEST', 'STRING', 'TEST STRING']
```

Comment: Why not just do a separate search for each string, and then join the results when you're done? Why do you need a single regular expression?

Comment: To make it more efficient. My list of values can be up to 50 words and I need to perform this task for over a million strings

Comment: Can you make clear what the input string(s) is/are, what you want to match and what the output you want should be?

Comment: Regex can't test each position twice

Comment: You can't use regex alternation group to test all alternatives. You will have to run 50 different regexps against each string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *Wiktor* commented, if you want to find **all** matches, you can not
use alternatives, because regex processor tries consecutive alternatives
and returns **only the first** alternative found.

So your program has to use a **separate** pattern for each value to test,
but for performance reason you can compile all of them in advance.

Another difference I spotted, between your Python instalation and mine
is `import regex`. Apparently you use some older Python version, as
I use  `import re` (version 3.7). I checked even Python version 2.7.15, it
**also** uses `import re`.

The script can look like below:

```
import re

def mtch(pat, str):
    s = pat.search(str)
    return s.group().upper() if s else None

# Strings to look for
values = ["test", "word", "string", "test string"]
# Compile patterns
patterns = [ re.compile(r'\b({})\b'.format(re.escape(v)),
    re.IGNORECASE) for v in values ]
# The string to check
string = "This is a test string"
# What has been found
list(filter(None, [ mtch(pat, string) for pat in patterns ]))
```

`mtch` function returns the text found by `pat` (the compiled pattern)
in `str` (source string) or *None* in the match failed.

`patterns` contains a list of compiled patterns.

Then there is `[ mtch(pat, string) for pat in patterns ]` a list
comprehension, generating match result list (with *None* values
if the match attempt failed).

To filter out *None* values I used `filter` function.

And finally `list` gathers all filtered strings and prints:

```
['TEST', 'STRING', 'TEST STRING']
```

If you want to perform this search for **multiple** source strings,
run **only the last** statement for each source string, probably adding
the result (and some indication of what string has been searched)
to some result list.

If your source list is very long, you should not attempt to read them all.
Instead, you should read them one by one in a loop and run the check
only for the current input string.

## Edit concerning comment as of 2019-02-18 10:00Z

As I read from your comment, the code reading strings is as follows:

```
with open("Test_data.csv") as f:
    for entry in f:
        entry = entry.split(',')
        string = entry[2] + " " + entry[3] + " " + entry[6]
```

Note that you overwrite `string` in every loop, so after the loop completed,
you have there the result from the **last** row (only).

Or maybe just after reading you run the search for patterns for the current
string?

Another hints to change the code:

1. Avoid such combinations that e.g. `entry` variable initially holds
   **the whole string** and then a **list** - product of splitting.
   Maybe a more readable variant is:

   ```
   for row in f:
       entry = row.split(',')
   ```
2. After you read a row and before doing anything else, check whether the row
   just read is **not empty**. If the row is empty, omit it.
   A quick way to test it is just to use the string in `if` (an empty string
   evaluates to *False*).

   ```
   for row in f:
       if row:
           entry = row.split(',')
           ...
   ```
3. Before `string = entry[2] + " " + entry[3] + " " + entry[6]` check
   whether `entry` list has at least 7 items (numeration is from 0).
   Maybe some of your input rows contain **smaller** number of fragments
   and hence your program attempts to read from a non-existing element of
   this list?
4. To be sure, what strings you are checking, write a short program
   which **only** splits the input and prints resulting strings. Then look at them, maybe you find something wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your well explained answer. I ran the code and it works but it seems to be much slower than my previous code. I am not sure what you meant by "If you want to perform this search for multiple source strings, run only the last statement for each source string". I do have multiple strings, but I also have multiple lists for `values` which I need to check. For each string I need to check all `values`

Comment: My intention was not to repeat compilation of patterns. Once they are compiled, you can use them to all source strings. And as far as execution time is concerned: Running multiple search (for individual patterns) must take longer than a single search with alternatives, but this is the right concept to do the job. Variant "with alternatives" will not find all matches.

Comment: Thank you for the edit you made on your code. I deleted my previous comment because I fixed the issue myself and it had nothing to do with your code. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you determine that `foobar` is in the text, you don't need to search the text separately for `foo` and `bar`: you know the answer already.

First group your searches:

```
searches = ['test', 'word', 'string', 'test string', 'wo', 'wordy']
unique = set(searches)
ordered = sorted(unique, key = len)
grouped = {}

while unique:
    s1 = ordered.pop()
    if s1 in unique:
        unique.remove(s1)
        grouped[s1] = [s1]
        redundant = [s2 for s2 in unique if s2 in s1]
        for s2 in redundant:
            unique.remove(s2)
            grouped[s1].append(s2)

for s, dups in grouped.items():
    print(s, dups)

# Output:
# test string ['test string', 'string', 'test']
# wordy ['wordy', 'word', 'wo']
```

Once you have things grouped, you can confine the searching to just the top-level searches (the keys of `grouped`).

Also, if scale and performance are concerns, do you really need regular expressions? Your current examples could be handled with ordinary `in` tests, which are faster. If you do indeed need regular expressions, the idea of grouping the searches is harder -- but perhaps not impossible under some conditions.