# Why do I get empty response for regexp_matches function while using positive lookahead (?=...)

Tags: regex, postgresql, posix

Why the following code returns just empty brackets - {''}. How to make it return matching strings?

`SELECT regexp_matches('ATGCATGCATGCCAACAACAACCTGTCAAGTGAGT','(?=..CAA)','g');`

Expected output is:

```
regexp_matches 
----------------
{GCCAA}
{AACAA}
{AACAA}
{GTCAA}
(4 rows)
```

but instead it returns the following:

```
 regexp_matches 
----------------
 {""}
 {""}
 {""}
 {""}
(4 rows)
```

I actually have a bit more complicated query, which requires positive lookahead in order to cover all occurrences of patterns in the string even if they overlap.

Comment: Your problem is that the positive lookahead is not part of the match. For your example, you don't need the lookahead anyway: just use `..CAA.`

Comment: Ah your matches can overlap. In that case you are out of luck with plain [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54723429/52598) but a few options have been mentioned.

Comment: `regexp_matches` does not seem to store the captured substrings with the capturing group inside a positive lookahead.

Comment: Using Powershell, it's possible to use the indexes returned from the lookaheads to use as index into your searchstring to get the substrings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not pretty, but you can do it without regular expressions or custom functions.

```
WITH data(d) as (
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('ATGCATGCATGCCAACAACAACCTGTCAAGTGAGT')) v
)
SELECT substr(d, x, 5) AS match
FROM data
JOIN LATERAL (SELECT generate_series(1, length(d))) g(x) ON TRUE
WHERE substr(d, x, 5) LIKE '__CAA'
;
 match
-------
 GCCAA
 AACAA
 AACAA
 GTCAA
(4 rows)
```

Basically, get each five letter slice of the string and see if it matches __CAA.

You could change `generate_series(1, length(d))` to `generate_series(1, length(d)-4)` because the last ones will never match, but you would have to remember to update this if the length of your matching string changes.

Comment: Thank you! It works nice, now will have to spend some time trying to understand how it works!

Answer (score 1):

- Using a lookahead has the problem that the lookahead itself is not part of the match but it allows overlapping searches
- Without using a lookahead, you lose the ability for overlapping searches.

Using Powershell, you can loop over the indexes returned from the lookaheads and use that as an index into your searchstring to get the matches

```
$string = 'ATGCATGCATGCCAACAACAACCTGTCAAGTGAGT'
$r = [regex]::new('(?=..CAA)')
$r.Matches($string) | % {$string.Substring($_.Index, 5)}
```

**returns**

```
GCCAA
AACAA
AACAA
GTCAA
```

I don't know how to translate this to PostgreSQL <sub>(or if that's even possible)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

***update:***
Aparently it won't capture inside of an assertion, that's ok because
what you really need is the first 2 characters, which can *safely* be
consumed. It will only give you the first 2 characters per row, but
since you know the last 3, you can easily join the set elements
with the `CAA` constant.

Try this

`..(?=CAA)`

and you're done.
If I knew the bizarre sql language, I could show you how to do the join.

Output should now be

```
match
-------
GC  
AA  
AA  
GT  
(4 rows)
```

---

This is the regex you need for overlapped matches.

`(?=(..CAA))`

https://regex101.com/r/eJ36zb/1

I think you just need this sql statement which captures group 1:

```
SELECT regexp_matches('ATGCATGCATGCCAACAACAACCTGTCAAGTGAGT','(?=(..CAA))','g');
```

Formatted regex

```
 (?=
      ( . . CAA )                   # (1)
 )
```

The reason you got empty strings in your result is that
you didn't give the expression anything to consume and
nothing to capture.

I.e., it matched at the right places, but nothing was consumed or captured.
So, doing it this way allows the overlap and the capture so it
should show up on the output now.

Comment: This would seem logical, but it returns the same results as not putting the parentheses in there.  From the manual about lookahead and lookbehind constraints: `all parentheses within them are considered non-capturing`.

Answer (score -1):

Lookahead is a zero-width assertion. It doesn't match anything. If you change your regular expression to just a regular match/capture, you'll get a result. For matching any two characters that are followed by `CAA` in your case, lookahead probably isn't necessary.

Comment: Yes, my bad - I have oversimplified the example. In this case it returns only 1 row
`SELECT regexp_matches('ATGCATGCATGCCAACAACAACCTGTCAAGTGAGT', '..CAACAA','g');
 regexp_matches 
----------------
 {GCCAACAA}
(1 row)` 
And I would like to get both matches - also AACAAACAA.